# Getting the value of the body of an executed function in R

Tags: r

The R language definition states that:

> The value returned by a function is the value of the function body,
>   which is usually an unassigned final expression, e.g.: `return()`

In other words, unless the function `return(...)` appears at some point during the function call, the value returned is the value of the body which can be edited throughout the function.

Is there a function in R that I can call in the body of the function that returns the value of the body at that point?

For example, calling such a function `bodyVal()`, consider the following

```
f <- function(x) {
    x^2
    print(bodyVal())
    x^3
    print(bodyVal())
}
```

`f` would then have the functionality demonstrated below:

```
> f(4)
[1] 16
[1] 64
> print(f(4))
[1] 16
[1] 64
[1] 64
```

It should be noted that in the first call, the value of `f(4)`, which is `64`, is itself not printed to the terminal.

It seems like R should be able to have such a function because the interpreter must keep track of the the value of the body, but I cannot find any documentation.

Comment: You're mis-reading that sentence.  The value of the function body is the _final_ expression.  Also, that quote is _not_ from the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html).  It's from a user-contributed document, [Programming in R](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r).

Comment: Actually the interpreter does *not* have to keep track of this value. All it needs to do is see which expression comes last in a function’s execution and retain *that*. This is a big difference. And to get the value of any given expression just assign it to a variable (or pass it to `print` directly).

Comment: Upvoting @KonradRudolph: Addendum:  If the body had been written with values being assigned to R names, then the local environment could have been inspected with a call to `ls()`. There is also a `.Last.value` object that can be used to recover the result of the last evaluation even when it was not assigned to a name.